# Why TypeScript incorrectly infers the return type?

Tags: typescript

**UPDATE:** **TypeScript message was correct**, the return type of that function could be an empty string.

The snippet below won't compile in TypeScript with `strictNullCheck` option.

The code is correct, but TS wrongly infers that this `(id) => id && /^[a-z0-9\-]+$/.test(id)` expression can return among other values empty string `''` and complains.

```
type Validators<D> = { 
  [K in keyof D]: (value: D[K] | undefined) => true | false | undefined
}

interface Post {
    id?: string
}

const validators: Validators<Post> = {
    // Complains about this line
    id: (id) => id && /^[a-z0-9\-]+$/.test(id) 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Validators%3CD%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20D%5D%3A%20(value%3A%20D%5BK%5D%20%7C%20undefined)%20%3D%3E%20true%20%7C%20false%20%7C%20undefined%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Post%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3F%3A%20string%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20validators%3A%20Validators%3CPost%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20(id)%20%3D%3E%20id%20%26%26%20%2F%5E%5Ba-z0-9%5C-%5D%2B%24%2F.test(id)%0A%7D)

Comment: but that expression **will** return an empty string if `id` is an empty string

Comment: @artem thanks, you are right, I didn't realised that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little trick I learned a while ago to assert non-null values is to do a double `!!`.

```
type Validators<D> = { 
  [K in keyof D]: (value: D[K] | undefined) => true | false | undefined
}

interface Post {
    id?: string
}

const validators: Validators<Post> = {
    id: (id) => !!id && /^[a-z0-9\-]+$/.test(id)
}
```

This code doesn't complain, but the thing it is unsure of is the `id` variable. By doing `!!id`, you're asserting it's falsiness, then flipping it to in essence assert its "truthiness".